# Is this angular momentum derivative always true?

Tags: physics, rotations, classical-mechanics

Recently, when asking for the derivative of angular momentum, I gave my own solution
$$ \frac {d \vec L} {dt} = \frac {d \vec r_{(t1)}} {dt} \times \frac {d \vec r_{(t2)}} {dt} + \vec r_{(t1)} \times  \frac {d^2 \vec r_{(t1)}} {dt}  \tag 1$$
[How to calculate the derivative of the angular momentum vector $ d\vec L = d(\hat I \vec \omega)?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961640/how-to-calculate-the-derivative-of-the-angular-momentum-vector-d-vec-l-d-ha)

Even though for a few examples I have counted, the derivative gave the correct result the question remained: is it always true?

I already have an answer, but first I have to ask a question, these are the rules here

Comment: What exactly is it you are exploring here? In the linked post you write *"I'm especially interested in derivative tensor to vector for the law of conservation of angular momentum for a rotating rigid body."* But there is no body defined, and no rotation visible. What is the claim you want to prove, what exactly does your notation mean?

Comment: What are $t1$ and $t2$? It looks to me that you are not computing the derivative, but maybe a finite difference.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I can't explain it in a short comment but in short: during the rotation of a rigid body (and more) there is a change in the moment of inertia which results in a change in the angular momentum but also an internal moment of force arises which gives exactly the opposite change in angular momentum, so that the law of conservation of angular momentum is not violated. Example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911524/how-to-calculate-force-vectors-acting-on-points-of-a-rotating-rigid-body

Comment: @nicola these are the times t1, t2, t3 .... giving time periods

Comment: Periods of what? Something like $\frac{dx}{dt}$ depends on $t$, not on $t1$ and $t2$. Your equation does not make much sense.

Comment: @nicola Sorry, but my English is poor and I'm not sure if I can explain it correctly. $\frac {dx} {dt} $ is limit of the sequence $\frac {x_{(t2)}-x_{(t1)}} {dt}$ where $t \rightarrow 0$

Comment: No, it's the limit where $t_2 \rightarrow t_1$ and $dt = t_2 - t_1$ (with a strange/wrong notation; $\Delta t$ should be at the denominator). There is no $t_2$ or $t_1$ if you solve that limit.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are dealing with some rigid body $B$ with density $\rho$.

I will use $r,z$ as vectors, $I,A,X$ as matrices in 3-dimensional space.

Such a rigid body is usually normalized in that its center of mass is zero and its principal axes to the inertia tensor $I$ are the coordinate axes, that is, $I$ is diagonal, where
$$
I=\int_B\rho(z) ((z^Tz)-zz^T)\,d{\rm vol}(z).
$$

This body moves with some displacement and rotation $r(t)+A(t)z$, $z\in B$. The path in the orthogonal matrices has a derivative $\dot A=AX$ where $X$ is an anti-symmetric matrix whose operation on vectors can be given as $Xz= ω\times z$. Then $\ddot A=\dot A X+A\dot X=AX^2+A\dot X$, so that
\begin{align}
\ddot Az=A(ω×(ω×z))&=A((ω^Tz)ω-|ω|^2z)\\
z^TA^T\ddot Az&=ω^Tzz^Tω-|ω|^2|z|^2\\
\int_B\rho(z)z^TA^T\ddot Az\,d{\rm vol}(z)&=-ω^TIω
\end{align}

The total angular momentum in an external or lab frame of the body is then
\begin{align}
L_e&=\int_B\rho(z)(r+Az)\times (\dot r+\dot A z)\,d{\rm vol}(z)\\
&=mr\times \dot r + \int_B\rho(z)(Az)\times (AX z)\,d{\rm vol}(z)\\
&=mr\times \dot r + A\int_B\rho(z) (z× (ω× z))\,d{\rm vol}(z)\\
&=mr\times \dot r + A\int_B\rho(z) ((z^Tz)ω- zz^Tω))\,d{\rm vol}(z)\\
&=mr\times \dot r + AIω.\\
\end{align}
One could now name $L_b=Iω$ the internal moment of inertia, relative to the body frame.

Then the derivative of the external moment, which is what is driving the mechanics in reacting to external forces, is
\begin{align}
\text{Then }~\dot L_e&=mr\times \ddot r + \dot AIω + AI\dot ω\\
&=mr\times \ddot r + AXIω + AI\dot ω\\
&=mr\times \ddot r + A[(ω×(Iω)) + I\dot ω]
\end{align}
Again one can split off the second term and relate it to the time evolution of the internal moment. I would not call it the time derivative,...

Comment: A very important question: whether $mr\times \ddot r$ it is the inner moment of force?

Comment: No, from the frame fixed to the body this term is not visible.

Comment: It is an inertial moment of force that compensates for the change in angular momentum caused by the change in the moment of inertia. https://youtu.be/8OnWhW1-15s . You just need to be able to see it, in the inertial frame of reference, the velocity vector changes with time, which is the result of this moment of force.

Comment: Your derivative is the correct answer to my previous question and there it should be https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961640/how-to-calculate-the-derivative-of-the-angular-momentum-vector-d-vec-l-d-ha . Here I am asking
  whether my derivative is true or not and we won't take it from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall m \in \Bbb R \land \forall \vec r_{(t1)}= (r_{1x},r_{1y},r_{1z}) \land \forall \vec r_{(t2)}= (r_{2x},r_{2y},r_{2z}) \land \forall \vec r_{(t3)}= (r_{3x},r_{3y},r_{3z})$$
$$(\frac {d \vec L} {dt}=\vec v_{(t1)}\times m \vec v_{(t2)} +\vec r_{(t1)} \times m \vec a_{(t1)} )$$

velocity and acceleration vectors

$$\frac {r_{2x} - r_{1x}}{dt} = \vec v_{x(t1)} ; \frac {r_{2y} - r_{1y}}{dt} = \vec v_{y(t1)}; \frac {r_{2z} - r_{1z}}{dt} = \vec v_{z(t1)} \tag 1  $$

$$\frac {r_{3x} - r_{2x}}{dt} = \vec v_{x(t2)} ; \frac {r_{3y} - r_{2y}}{dt} = \vec v_{y(t2)}; \frac {r_{3z} - r_{2z}}{dt} = \vec v_{z(t2)} \tag 2  $$

$$\frac {v_{2x} - v_{1x}}{dt} = \vec a_{x(t1)} ; \frac {v_{2y} - v_{1y}}{dt} = \vec a_{y(t1)}; \frac {v_{2z} - v_{1z}}{dt} = \vec a_{z(t1)} \tag 3  $$

angular momentum vectors

$$\vec L_{(t1)}= \vec r_{(t1)} \times m \vec v_{(t1)}   $$
$$(r_{1y}v_{1z} - r_{1z}v_{1y}, r_{1z}v_{1x}-r_{1x}v_{1z},r_{1x}v_{1y} -r_{1y}v_{1x}) \tag 4 $$
$$\vec L_{(t2)}= \vec r_{(t2)} \times m \vec v_{(t2)}   $$
$$(r_{2y}v_{2z} - r_{2z}v_{2y}, r_{2z}v_{2x}-r_{2x}v_{2z},r_{2x}v_{2y} -r_{2y}v_{2x}) \tag 5 $$
change of angular momentum vector with time
$$\vec L_{(t2)}-\vec L_{(t1)} \tag 6$$

$$\frac {d l_{x}}{dt}=m(r_{2y}v_{2z}-r_{1y}v_{1z}-r_{2z}v_{2y}+r_{1z}v_{1y}) \tag {6.a}$$
$$\frac {d l_{y}}{dt}=m(r_{2z}v_{2x}-r_{1z}v_{1x}-r_{2x}v_{2z}+r_{1x}v_{1z}) \tag {6.b}$$
$$\frac {d l_{z}}{dt}=m(r_{2x}v_{2y}-r_{1x}v_{1y}-r_{2y}v_{2x}+r_{1y}v_{1x}) \tag {6.c}$$

we calculate the components of the derivative

$$\vec v_{(t1)}\times \vec v_{(t2)}=(v_{1y}v_{2z} - v_{1z}v_{2y}, v_{1z}v_{2x}-v_{1x}v_{2z},v_{1x}v_{2y} -v_{1y}v_{2x}) \tag 7$$

$$v_{1y}v_{2z} - v_{1z}v_{2y}=r_{2y}v_{2z}-r_{1y}v_{2z} -r_{2z}v_{2y}+r_{1z}v_{2y}\tag {7.a}$$
$$v_{1z}v_{2x} - v_{1x}v_{2z}=r_{2z}v_{2x}-r_{1z}v_{2x} -r_{2x}v_{2z}+r_{1x}v_{2z}\tag {7.b}$$
$$v_{1x}v_{2y} - v_{1y}v_{2x}=r_{2x}v_{2y}-r_{1x}v_{2y} -r_{2y}v_{2x}+r_{1y}v_{2x}\tag {7.c}$$

$$\vec r_{(t1)}\times \vec a_{(t1)}=(r_{1y}a_{1z} - r_{1z}a_{1y}, r_{1z}a_{1x}-r_{1x}a_{1z},r_{1x}a_{1y} -r_{1y}a_{1x}) \tag 8$$

$$r_{1y}a_{1z} - r_{1z}a_{1y}=r_{1y}v_{2z}-r_{1y}v_{1z} -r_{1z}v_{2y}+r_{1z}v_{1y}\tag {8.a}$$
$$r_{1z}a_{1x} - r_{1x}a_{1z}=r_{1z}v_{2x}-r_{1z}v_{1x} -r_{1x}v_{2z}+r_{1x}v_{1z}\tag {8.b}$$
$$r_{1x}a_{1y} - r_{1y}a_{1x}=r_{1x}v_{2y}-r_{1x}v_{1y} -r_{1y}v_{2x}+r_{1y}v_{1x}\tag {8.c}$$
We count the derivative
$$\frac {d \vec L`} {dt}=\vec v_{(t1)}\times m \vec v_{(t2)} +\vec r_{(t1)} \times m \vec a_{(t1)} \tag 9$$

$$\frac {d l`_{x}}{dt}=m(r_{2y}v_{2z}-r_{1y}v_{1z}-r_{2z}v_{2y}+r_{1z}v_{1y}) \tag {9.a}$$
$$\frac {d l`_{y}}{dt}=m(r_{2z}v_{2x}-r_{1z}v_{1x}-r_{2x}v_{2z}+r_{1x}v_{1z}) \tag {9.b}$$
$$\frac {d l`_{z}}{dt}=m(r_{2x}v_{2y}-r_{1x}v_{1y}-r_{2y}v_{2x}+r_{1y}v_{1x}) \tag {9.c}$$

$$(6)=(9)$$

C.K.D.