# $ \vec r \times m \frac {\delta^2 \vec r} {\delta^2 t} \neq \frac {\delta \vec L}{\delta t} $?

Tags: vectors, physics, rotations, classical-mechanics

$$\forall m \land \forall \vec r_{(t1)}(r_{1x},r_{1y},r_{1z}) \land \forall \vec r_{(t2)}(r_{2x},r_{2y},r_{2z}) \land \forall \vec r_{(t3)}(r_{3x},r_{3y},r_{3z}) $$
$$\vec v_{(t1)}=\frac {\vec r_{(t2)} - \vec r_{(t1)}} {\delta t} \tag {1.a} $$
$$\vec v_{(t2)}=\frac {\vec r_{(t3)} - \vec r_{(t2)}} {\delta t} \tag {1.b} $$
$$\vec a_{(t1)}=\frac {\vec v_{(t2)} - \vec v_{(t1)}} {\delta t} \tag {1.c} $$
$$ \vec r_{(t1)} \times  m \vec v_{(t1)}=m(r_{1y} v_{1z} -r_{1z} v_{1y},r_{1z} v_{1x} -r_{1x} v_{1z},r_{1x} v_{1y} -r_{1y} v_{1x})= \vec L_{(t1)} \tag {2.a}  $$
$$ \vec r_{(t2)} \times  m \vec v_{(t2)}=m(r_{2y} v_{2z} -r_{2z} v_{2y},r_{2z} v_{2x} -r_{2x} v_{2z},r_{2x} v_{2y} -r_{2y} v_{2x})= \vec L_{(t2)} \tag {2.b}  $$
$$\frac {\vec L_{(t2)}-\vec L_{(t1)}} {\delta t} =(\frac {\delta l_{x}}{\delta t}, \frac {\delta l_{y}}{\delta t},\frac {\delta l_{z}}{\delta t} ) \tag 3$$
$$\frac {\delta l_{x}}{\delta t}=m(r_{2y}v_{2z}-r_{1y}v_{1z}-r_{2z}v_{2y}+r_{1z}v_{1y}) \tag {3.a}$$
$$\frac {\delta l_{y}}{\delta t}=m(r_{2z}v_{2x}-r_{1z}v_{1x}-r_{2x}v_{2z}+r_{1x}v_{1z}) \tag {3.b}$$
$$\frac {\delta l_{z}}{\delta t}=m(r_{2x}v_{2y}-r_{1x}v_{1y}-r_{2y}v_{2x}+r_{1y}v_{1x}) \tag {3.c}$$

$$\vec r_{(t1)}\times m \vec a_{(t1)}=m(r_{1y}a_{1z} - r_{1z}a_{1y}, r_{1z}a_{1x}-r_{1x}a_{1z},r_{1x}a_{1y} -r_{1y}a_{1x}) \tag 4$$

$$r_{1y}a_{1z} - r_{1z}a_{1y}=r_{1y}v_{2z}-r_{1y}v_{1z} -r_{1z}v_{2y}+r_{1z}v_{1y}\tag {4.a}$$
$$r_{1z}a_{1x} - r_{1x}a_{1z}=r_{1z}v_{2x}-r_{1z}v_{1x} -r_{1x}v_{2z}+r_{1x}v_{1z}\tag {4.b}$$
$$r_{1x}a_{1y} - r_{1y}a_{1x}=r_{1x}v_{2y}-r_{1x}v_{1y} -r_{1y}v_{2x}+r_{1y}v_{1x}\tag {4.c}$$

$$(4) \neq (3)$$

Correct pattern
$$  \frac {\delta \vec L}{\delta t} = m( \frac {\delta \vec r_{(t1)}} {\delta t} \times  \frac {\delta \vec r_{(t2)}} {\delta t} +  \vec r_{(t1)} \times   \frac {\delta^2 \vec r_{(t1)}} {\delta^2 t})   \tag 5$$

I proved it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044211/is-this-angular-momentum-derivative-always-true/4044256#4044256) but this result $(4) \neq (3)$ is contrary to bookish knowledge and (5) changes the understanding of point rotation, since this formula allows for the existence of non-zero internal moments of force, lawful conservation of angular momentum.

So the question is: I am wrong in the calculations or maybe the present knowledge is wrong?

Comment: If you note that $a×b=(a-b)×b=a×(b-a)$ then you see that the first term on the right in (5) is infinitesimal against the other two terms which have an appreciable value.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I still trying to understand better $\vec v_1 \times \vec v_2$ but for one thing I am sure that this result is not always zero. Of course there are special cases where this term is zero but in the cases where we have a velocity vector along the position vector or along the angular momentum vector, then we have values other than zero. If you want to see zero, you will be counting special examples If you want to know the truth, you have to count other cases as well. I believe you can count it but I doubt you are afraid to see it.

Comment: Essentially, what you have shown here is that if one integrates the equations of motions with the Euler method, the angular momentum will not behave as physics demands, will not be constant, as example, in a central force field. But no-one expects that from an Euler method integration.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I did not break the conservation of angular momentum but I showed that equation $\vec r \times m \vec a = d \vec L$ is not true, it means it is not complete because there is something missing that you don't know and understand. I showed the solution (5) but it is ignored and you don't want to see it because it's not what you expect. To understand this, various examples have to be calculate and you must open minds to new solutions. What you think is impossible but it is part of Physics.

Answer (score 0):

As I said somewhere, I prefer the symmetric discretizations that have automatically a higher order of accuracy. So with some infinitesimal $δt$ set $t_k=t_0+\frac12k\,δt$. Then $a_0=\frac{v_1-v_{-1}}{δt}+O(δt^2)$, $v_1=\frac{r_2-r_0}{δt}+O(δt^2)$, $v_{-1}$ similarly, and
\begin{align}
\frac{r_1×v_1-r_{-1}×v_{-1}}{δt}
&=\frac{(r_1-r_{-1})×(v_1+v_{-1})}{2δt}+\frac{(r_1+r_{-1})×(v_1-v_{-1})}{2δt}
\\
&=\frac{(v_0+O(δt)^2)×(v_0+O(δt)^2)}{2δt}+\frac{(r_0+O(δt)^2)×(a_0+O(δt)^2)}{2}
\\
&=r_0×a_0+O(δt^2)
\end{align}
Now remember that as an infinitesimal $δt$ has a decimal representation with a mind-boggling number of zeros after the decimal dot. This transfers to the remainder $O(δt^2)$. So in all integrations over finite time spans this remainder contributes at most $O(δt)$, which has no appreciable influence.

Comment: I checked $r_1 \times v_1 - r_0 \times v_0$ is not equal $((r_1 - r_0) \times (v_1 + v_0) + (r_1 + r_0) \times (v_1 - v_0))/2 $

Comment: No idea why the minus happened there, it was from the start intended to be a sum, so that the mixed terms cancel.

Comment: example $r_0(r_{x0},0,0);r_1(r_{x1},r_{y1},0);v_0(0,v_{y0},0);v_1(v_{x1},v_{y1},0)$ the left side will not be equal to the right side whether it is a sum or a difference